# We don't remember Apple email or id and now can not use ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, email, apple-id, password

It is ipad 3 with a1416 model

It is currently factory reset but it keeps saying this ipad is bound to an apple id

It freakingly shows only first letter of the email which doesn't help at all

We don't remember the email. It wasn't used for a long time later its screen was broken so we sent it to the service and they changed screen along with factory reset

Now we can't access the device and we do not remember its apple id or email or password

I tried recovery mode but all goes to this ipad bound to apple id so enter its password

What can i do? Now this owned device became a trash?

I always hated apple and now i hate 10x more. I am not able to use a device that i own.

Comment: Go to appleid.apple.com and reset your Apple ID password.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that your AppleID is required is for security reasons.   If you were to lose your iPad or have it stolen, and anyone could just factory reset it and make it theirs, then you'd be upset that Apple allows anyone to register on a stolen iPad.

So, when an iPad is reset the normal way (you are logged in, you select to reset from the menu), your ID is automatically removed so that it can be associated with any ID afterwards.

In your case...  since this was not done, the iPad is still bound to your Apple ID.   As you mentioned, you don't recall what this is...  but do you really have so many email addresses that you aren't able to guess at the right one given the first character?

I suggest visiting https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid#!&section=appleid to try and figure out what your ID was... as there is no way to remove an ID from the iPad in the current state (again, for security reasons).